# Exclude specific library from one build variant in android

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

In my android app, I have multiple flavors like below:

```
    productFlavors {

    playStore {
        dimension "market"
    }

    webSite {
        dimension "market"
    }
}
```

I used many libraries, but some of them are useless in play store flavor and they cause the increase in app size. How can I exclude them in one flavor while those libraries have used in common java files?

Comment: If you set up a well detailed proguard file to your release apk, this will be enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude some library from `playStore` apk set it as:

```
playStoreCompileOnly <lib>
webSiteImplementation <lib>
```

This will add it to `playStore` compile classpath to make compilation possible, but it won't be included in an apk file. `webSite` apk will contain it.

Comment: It should be writted in proguardrules? @Artyom